# C++ references& and memory

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

I'm writing a code and I have a question about references&:

```
class A{
    private:
            int num;
    public:
            void set(const int& a){num = a;}
            void foo(){
                    int a = 4;
                    set(a);
            }
            void print(){
                    cout << num << endl;
            }

};  
int main(){
    A a;
    a.foo();
    a.print();
    return 0;
}
```

In this case, the variable `a` will be destroyed at the end of  `foo()`. `set` take the reference, so the address of `a` and updates `num`. Therefore is this code wrong (num points to a deleted memory)? Or `set`, sets num with the **value** (not the address) of a?

I edit the code with a `cout` of address of `a` and `num` and they are different, so I think that num copies the **value** of `a`. If I run the code, all seems works, but I'm not sure.

Comment: `num = a;` takes a copy, nothing special. _"num points to a deleted memory"_ no `num` doesn't point to memory, it's a plain class member variable.

Comment: A copy of tha value of a, not the address, right?

Comment: _"A copy of tha value of a, not the address, right?"_ Sure.

Answer (score 2):

Your code isn't invalid, because the code `num = a`, takes a copy of a. Plus, `set()` is called BEFORE the objects memory is returned, so everyone has a copy, and nothing invalid happens. Also, remember, that `num` lasts while the class's instance lasts, so don't worry about deleted memory.

Comment: @linofex What on earth gives you the idea an address is copied there?

Comment: No, the address is not copied, these aren't pointers. An example of when two objects would refer to the same address is when a class has a pointer member allocated with new, and copy construction/assignment is not defined for it.

Comment: My question derivs from set  takes the reference of an int, so the address  word make my doubtful

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't happen here

Comment: Also, don't forget that the parameter is a _CONST_ reference